# Aplicação Mobile usando emissor IR com Delphi XE5 ou Superior

Tags: delphi, mobile

Gostaria de saber se existe a possibilidade de desenvolver uma aplicação mobile em Delphi XE5 ou superior, em que pudesse enviar sinal Infravermelho (IR) para qualquer receptor, por exemplo uma TV.

Comment: Como existe dependencia do hardware, você vai precisar saber se o aparelho possui tal recurso e se o sistema operacional disponibiliza tal API. Sua pergunta é muito genérica.

Comment: Pode até ser genérica, mas cabível de resposta, gostaria de saber se alguém já fez alguma aplicação em Delphi XE5 + que utilizasse o sensor IR, se já existe componente ou alguma biblioteca para os dispositivos que contemplam este sensor.

Answer (score 3):

Acho que entendi sua ideia, você quer fazer um tipo de controle universal para a sua casa e operá-lo pelo celular.

Se for para vender a aplicação, eu sugiro que você faça um emissor infravermelho que funcione com rede e que você opere o mesmo pelo WiFi do celular, porque a maioria dos aparelhos hoje não tem esse hardware incluso.

Mas se for para uso específico isso já foi feito basta procurar na Play Store que você acha vários deles.

Em relação ao Delphi, acredito que exista mais literaturas e documentação para Java.

De uma olhada nisso e procure mais videos a respeito.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3lqEzpZeBwo

**Em questão de Java tenho:**

Transmissores infravermelho

Quando executado em um dispositivo que inclui um transmissor de infravermelho (IR), agora você pode transmitir sinais de IR usando as APIs ConsumerIrManager. Para obter uma instância do ConsumerIrManager, chame o método getSystemService() com CONSUMER_IR_SERVICE como argumento. Você pode, então, consultar frequências suportadas IR do dispositivo com getCarrierFrequencies() e transmitir sinais passando o seu padrão de frequência e sinal desejado com transmit().

Você deve sempre verificar primeiro se o dispositivo inclui um transmissor IR chamando o método hasIrEmitter(), mas se o seu aplicativo é compatível somente com dispositivos que têm um, você deve incluir um elemento  no seu manifesto para "android.hardware.consumerir"( FEATURE_CONSUMER_IR ).

**Original**
"Infrared transmitters

When running on a device that includes an infrared (IR) transmitter, you can now transmit IR signals using the ConsumerIrManager APIs. To get an instance of ConsumerIrManager, call getSystemService() with CONSUMER_IR_SERVICE as the argument. You can then query the device's supported IR frequencies with getCarrierFrequencies() and transmit signals by passing your desired frequency and signal pattern with transmit().

You should always first check whether a device includes an IR transmitter by calling hasIrEmitter(), but if your app is compatible only with devices that do have one, you should include a  element in your manifest for "android.hardware.consumerir" (FEATURE_CONSUMER_IR)."

Fonte https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html#Wireless

**A classe ConsumerIrManager:** https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/ConsumerIrManager.html

Acredito que só funcione no KitKat mas não é certeza. 
link kitkat: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/kitkat.html

**Documentação da XDA developpers**
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1670289

**Achei esse código exemplo**

```
    package com.rngtng.irdude;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Object irdaService;
    Method irWrite;
    SparseArray<String> irData;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        irData = new SparseArray<String>();
        irData.put(
                R.id.buttonPower,
                hex2dec("0000 006d 0022 0002 0152 00aa 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 003f 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0696 0152 0055 0015 0e23"));
        irData.put(
                R.id.buttonVolDown,
                hex2dec("0000 006d 0022 0002 0152 00aa 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 003f 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 003f 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 0015 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0696 0152 0055 0015 0e23"));
        irData.put(
                R.id.buttonMute,
                hex2dec("0000 006d 0022 0002 0152 00aa 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 003f 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 0015 0015 003f 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 0015 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0696 0152 0055 0015 0e23"));
        irData.put(
                R.id.buttonVolUp,
                hex2dec("0000 006d 0022 0002 0152 00aa 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 003f 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 0015 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0696 0152 0055 0015 0e23"));
        irData.put(
                R.id.buttonTuner,
                hex2dec("0000 006d 0022 0002 0152 00aa 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 003f 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 0015 0015 003f 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 003f 0015 0015 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 0015 0015 0696 0152 0055 0015 0e23"));
        irData.put(
                R.id.buttonPhono,
                hex2dec("0000 006d 0022 0002 0154 00aa 0014 0016 0014 0016 0014 0016 0014 0016 0014 0016 0014 0016 0014 0016 0014 0041 0014 0016 0014 0016 0014 0016 0014 0016 0014 0041 0013 0041 0014 0041 0014 0016 0014 0016 0014 0041 0013 0017 0013 0017 0013 0017 0013 0017 0013 0041 0014 0041 0014 0041 0013 0017 0013 0041 0014 0041 0014 0041 0013 0041 0014 0016 0014 0016 0014 06bf 0154 0056 0014 0e6b"));
        irData.put(
                R.id.buttonCD,
                hex2dec("0000 006d 0022 0002 0152 00aa 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 003f 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 003f 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 0015 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 003f 0015 0015 0015 0015 0015 0696 0152 0055 0015 0e23"));
        irData.put(
                R.id.buttonAux,
                hex2dec("0000 006d 0022 0002 0154 00aa 0014 0016 0014 0016 0014 0016 0014 0016 0014 0016 0014 0016 0014 0016 0014 0041 0014 0016 0014 0016 0014 0016 0014 0016 0014 0041 0013 0041 0014 0041 0014 0016 0014 0016 0014 0041 0013 0041 0014 0041 0014 0016 0014 0016 0014 0041 0013 0041 0014 0041 0014 0016 0014 0016 0014 0016 0014 0041 0013 0041 0014 0016 0014 0016 0014 06bf 0154 0057 0013 0e6b"));

        irInit();
    }

    public void irInit() {
        irdaService = this.getSystemService("irda");
        Class c = irdaService.getClass();
        Class p[] = { String.class };
        try {
            irWrite = c.getMethod("write_irsend", p);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void irSend(View view) {
        String data = irData.get(view.getId());
        if (data != null) {
            try {
                irWrite.invoke(irdaService, data);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    protected String hex2dec(String irData) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(irData
                .split(" ")));
        list.remove(0); // dummy
        int frequency = Integer.parseInt(list.remove(0), 16); // frequency
        list.remove(0); // seq1
        list.remove(0); // seq2

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            list.set(i, Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(list.get(i), 16)));
        }

        frequency = (int) (1000000 / (frequency * 0.241246));
        list.add(0, Integer.toString(frequency));

        irData = "";
        for (String s : list) {
            irData += s + ",";
        }
        return irData;
    }

}
```

**Outro código que você pode usar como base Open sourse da google**

```
    /*
 * Copyright (C) 20013The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package com.example.android.apis.hardware;
// Need the following import to get access to the app resources, since this
// class is in a sub-package.
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.hardware.ConsumerIrManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.util.Log;
import com.example.android.apis.R;
/**
 * App that transmit an IR code
 *
 * <p>This demonstrates the {@link android.hardware.ConsumerIrManager android.hardware.ConsumerIrManager} class.
 *
 * <h4>Demo</h4>
 * Hardware / Consumer IR
 *
 * <h4>Source files</h4>
 * <table class="LinkTable">
 *         <tr>
 *             <td>src/com.example.android.apis/hardware/ConsumerIr.java</td>
 *             <td>Consumer IR demo</td>
 *         </tr>
 *         <tr>
 *             <td>res/any/layout/consumer_ir.xml</td>
 *             <td>Defines contents of the screen</td>
 *         </tr>
 * </table>
 */
public class ConsumerIr extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "ConsumerIrTest";
    TextView mFreqsText;
    ConsumerIrManager mCIR;
    /**
     * Initialization of the Activity after it is first created.  Must at least
     * call {@link android.app.Activity#setContentView setContentView()} to
     * describe what is to be displayed in the screen.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Be sure to call the super class.
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get a reference to the ConsumerIrManager
        mCIR = (ConsumerIrManager)getSystemService(Context.CONSUMER_IR_SERVICE);
        // See assets/res/any/layout/consumer_ir.xml for this
        // view layout definition, which is being set here as
        // the content of our screen.
        setContentView(R.layout.consumer_ir);
        // Set the OnClickListener for the button so we see when it's pressed.
        findViewById(R.id.send_button).setOnClickListener(mSendClickListener);
        findViewById(R.id.get_freqs_button).setOnClickListener(mGetFreqsClickListener);
        mFreqsText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.freqs_text);
    }
    View.OnClickListener mSendClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!mCIR.hasIrEmitter()) {
                Log.e(TAG, "No IR Emitter found\n");
                return;
            }
            // A pattern of alternating series of carrier on and off periods measured in
            // microseconds.
            int[] pattern = {1901, 4453, 625, 1614, 625, 1588, 625, 1614, 625, 442, 625, 442, 625,
                468, 625, 442, 625, 494, 572, 1614, 625, 1588, 625, 1614, 625, 494, 572, 442, 651,
                442, 625, 442, 625, 442, 625, 1614, 625, 1588, 651, 1588, 625, 442, 625, 494, 598,
                442, 625, 442, 625, 520, 572, 442, 625, 442, 625, 442, 651, 1588, 625, 1614, 625,
                1588, 625, 1614, 625, 1588, 625, 48958};
            // transmit the pattern at 38.4KHz
            mCIR.transmit(38400, pattern);
        }
    };
    View.OnClickListener mGetFreqsClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
            if (!mCIR.hasIrEmitter()) {
                mFreqsText.setText("No IR Emitter found!");
                Log.e(TAG, "No IR Emitter found!\n");
                return;
            }
            // Get the available carrier frequency ranges
            ConsumerIrManager.CarrierFrequencyRange[] freqs = mCIR.getCarrierFrequencies();
            b.append("IR Carrier Frequencies:\n");
            for (ConsumerIrManager.CarrierFrequencyRange range : freqs) {
                b.append(String.format("    %d - %d\n", range.getMinFrequency(),
                            range.getMaxFrequency()));
            }
            mFreqsText.setText(b.toString());
        }
    };
}
```

**Achei mais isso de documentação:**
http://www.irdroid.com/

**Aqui um projetinho completo no github**
https://github.com/Irdroid/Irdroid

**Usa esse aqui como inspiração**
http://www.myuremote.com/website/how-to-add-ir-commands-to-the-myuremote-device-database/

Comment: Sim quero fazer um controle universal para minha casa, mas infelizmente ar condicionado por exemplo não vem com wifi, então não posso controlar com o meu smartphone, sei que já existem aplicação na google play, mas existem hardwares específicos que eu mesmo fabrico com receptor IR, o que procuro é algum componente ou DLL que possa usar no Delphi para resolver minha situação.

Comment: Então ano passado eu tinha essa mesma ideia que você,
pesquisei bastante, achei umas coisas interessantes até. 
mas cheguei a conclusão que seria bem mais fácil criar um sistema de emissor de infravermelho com aqueles difusores(igual sensor de presença) e um modulo WIFI ou Bluetooth e colocar um por comodo. 
na época eu tinha cotado isso, acho que sairia algo em torno de 10 pila mais acabamento, 
assim vc consegue sempre emitir IV para todos os equipamentos da sua casa estando no seu quarto por exemplo

Comment: adicionei umas documentações que encontrei

Comment: Estava lendo agora mesmo sobre as APIs, e realmente só vai funcionar com kitkat, mas não importa.

Comment: Adcionei um código que achei na net(não sei se funciona) e uma documentação da XDA devellopers

Comment: adicionei outras informações e uma fonte de inspiração para designe do seu projeto